# Convert SQL query to eloquent query for update table in Laravel

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent, sql-update

I want to convert this SQL query to an eloquent query for the update table but get the error `ORA-00971: missing SET keyword`

```sql
UPDATE services
SET services.statement_id = (
    SELECT statements.id
    FROM statements 
    WHERE services.service_ref = statements.statement_ref
)
```

this my eloquent query

```
DB::select('UPDATE services SET services.statement_id = (SELECT statements.id
        FROM statements 
        WHERE services.service_ref = statements.statement_ref)');
```

I want to update data with join laravel

Comment: Are you certain this query works when you use it directly in the database?

Comment: You converted it to query builder not eloquent. You can use `raw` method of query builder instead

Answer (score 0):

use :

```
DB::select(DB::raw('UPDATE services SET services.statement_id = (SELECT statements.id
        FROM statements 
        WHERE services.service_ref = statements.statement_ref)'));
```